# Custom text and background color in subtitles FFMPEG | Converting HEX to AARRGGBB

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

I have this code that was working fine with text color only but when I added the background using outline to draw box around subtitles it started outputing weird colors, for example using black #000 I got red

```
 var alpha = 1.0;

  const textColorHex = "#000000";
  const textColor = `&H${tinycolor(textColorHex).setAlpha(alpha).toHex8().substr(2)}`;
  // textColor : &H0000ff

  const bgColorHex = '#ffffff';
  const bgColor = `&H${tinycolor(bgColorHex).setAlpha(alpha).toHex8().substr(2)}`;
  // bgColor : &Hffffff


  const ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", [
    "-i",
    "test.mp4",
    "-vf",
    `subtitles=${subtitlePath}:force_style='Alignment=${alignment},OutlineColour=${bgColor},BorderStyle=3,PrimaryColour=${textColor},Fontsize=${fontSize}'`,
    "-c:a",
    "copy",
    "-progress", "pipe:1",
    outputPath,
  ]);
```

I am not sure how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

These color formats are draconian. This is the best reference I've found:

[Field Descriptions](https://fileformats.fandom.com/wiki/SubStation_Alpha#Fields)

[Data Types](https://fileformats.fandom.com/wiki/SubStation_Alpha#Data_types)

> Color values are expressed in hexadecimal BGR format as &HBBGGRR& or ABGR (with alpha channel) as &HAABBGGRR&. Transparency (alpha) can be expressed as &HAA&. Note that in the alpha channel, 00 is opaque and FF is transparent.

I use this script to convert RGBA to the required format:

```js
export function RGBAToHexAss(r: number, g: number, b: number, a: number) {
  let red = r.toString(16);
  let green = g.toString(16);
  let blue = b.toString(16);

  let inverseAlpha = 1 - a;

  let alpha = Math.round(inverseAlpha * 255).toString(16);

  if (red.length == 1)
    red = "0" + red;
  if (green.length == 1)
    green = "0" + green;
  if (blue.length == 1)
    blue = "0" + blue;
  if (alpha.length == 1)
    alpha = "0" + alpha;

  return "&H" + alpha + blue + green + red;
}
```