# How to convert HEX colors to AARRGGBB format to use in FFMPEG?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert hex colors in JavaScript but I am always getting the wrong code outputted here what I've tried so far

```
const bgColorHex = '#FFBA08'; 
const bgColorFFmpeg = `&H${tinycolor(bgColorHex).toHex8().substr(2)}`;
```

Second method

```js
const hexColor = "EF233C";
const alpha = 1.0;

const r = parseInt(hexColor.slice(0, 2), 16);
const g = parseInt(hexColor.slice(2, 4), 16);
const b = parseInt(hexColor.slice(4, 6), 16);
const a = Math.round(alpha * 255);

const argbColor = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

console.log(argbColor.toString(16));
```

I cannot figure this out all I get working is black and white on FFMPEG

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76172256/215552

Comment: To use in FFmpeg how? https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Color already supports the same hex format used here (and the optional alpha component goes at the end).

Comment: If you provide the ffmpeg command you're using we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const bgColorHex = '#FFBA08'; 
const bgColorFFmpeg = bgColorHex.replace('#', '&HFF');
console.log(bgColorFFmpeg);
```